# Checkbox onCheck doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mobx

I have a checkbox from material-ui that doesn't fire onCheck event.

```
<Checkbox
  label="label"
  onCheck={onCheck}
  checked={currentDocument.ispublic}
/>


function onCheck() {
  currentDocument.ispublic = !currentDocument.ispublic;
  console.log("onCheck");
}
```

I tried removing checked property as described in this question: [React Checkbox not sending onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615779/react-checkbox-not-sending-onchange)

currentDocument is an observable object stored in my store.

Comment: try to bind your method oncheck={method.bind(this)}

Comment: Jsx props should not use bind()

Comment: "currentDocument is an observable object stored in my store." Does it allow you to mutate it ?

Comment: @Dyo I changed checked to false, but the event still doesn't fire.

Comment: @Elminday Your given example works for me. Perhaps you could provide more of the surrounding component or a full reproduction?

Answer (score 2):

Can it be because based on https://material-ui-next.com/api/checkbox/#checkbox material-ui is exposing onChange not onCheck?

Comment: `material-ui@next` and `material-ui` are not same package

Comment: `material-ui` Checkbox exposes `onChange` not `onCheck`.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full content, there is no way to test your code.
But there are some possible errors:

- Where do `onCheck` and `currentDocument` come from? If it's in the component class, you need put `this` keyword.
- Use arrow function for `onCheck`, otherwise, you can't access `this` without `.bind(this)`
- The component class should have decorator `@observer` and `currentDocument` should have `@observable`

The code below is one possible answer, but I'm not sure what behavior you expected, so I didn't test. However, with MobX, the syntax is correct.

```
@observer
class MyCheckBox extends React.Component {
  @observable currentDocument = {
    ispublic: false,
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <Checkbox
        label="label"
        onCheck={this.onCheck}
        checked={this.currentDocument.ispublic}
      />
    );
  }

  onCheck = () => {
    this.currentDocument.ispublic = !this.currentDocument.ispublic;
  }
}
```