# Title of Checkbox component of Material-ui is not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The title attribute is not working correctly on the checkbox, when the mouse is on the area serrounding the checkbox it works but not when the mouse is on the input element.

This is my checkbox code:

```
const StyledCheckbox = withStyles({
colorPrimary: {
    borderColor: '#757575',
    borderRadius: 1,
    '&$checked': {
        color: '#00adb3'
    },
},
checked: {},})(Checkbox);
```

and the render

```
 public render() {
    return <>
        <div className='checkbox-react'>
            <StyledCheckbox  color='primary' checked={this.state.checked} onClick={this.handleChange}
                                     title={'test test'}  onChange={this.handleChange}   />
        </div>
    </>;
}
```

Here's an example
[image]
[image]

Comment: could be something about the event handlers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615779/react-checkbox-not-sending-onchange#answer-52386786

Comment: What is the CSS that is styling the look of the `title`. The `title` seems to work fine for me [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mopz17oq4y), but the look I'm seeing is just the browser default title behavior and it looks like you have something else.

Comment: Can you replicate your issue in codesandbox?