# Checkboxes to change state and filter list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry i am still petty new at this, just in case there is code someone wants to see that i negelct to embed here is the whole code [Gist](https://gist.github.com/RecoveringChef/72ba30cb30ee313eb5b54479274bef08)

Anyway I am using checkboxes in list A to setState so a method can then filter items from list B and only display those with ObjectID's associated.

I am not sure if my `checkboxes` are not properly setting the state, or if my method is not working right.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {   
        conditions: [],
        symptoms: [],
        selectedSymptom: []
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getConditionsMethod();
        this.getSymptomsMethod();
    }

    getConditionsMethod = () => {
        API.getConditions()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
                this.setState({
                    conditions: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };

    getSymptomsMethod = () => {
      API.getSymptoms()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                this.setState({
                    symptoms: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };

    filterConditionsMethod = () => {
        API.getConditions()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                data.data.filter(condition => !condition.symptoms.includes(this.state.selectedSymptom || this.state.selectedSymptom.length))
                this.setState({
                    selectedSymptom: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
```

later in my return

```
<div className="doubleCol">
    {this.state.symptoms.map(item => (
    <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
        <input name="slector"
               type="checkbox"
               className="sympSelect"
               onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedSymptom: true })}
        />
        {item.name}
    </ListItem>
    ))}
</div>
```

I have spent 2 weeks building this app, and have been stuck on this filtering for the last 2 days. 
I need to have this app MVP by tomorrow afternoon for demo at an employment event for recent grads and this is one of only 2 things left.

I don't have enough rep for a bounty, but ANY help or advice appreciated

Comment: Can you share your code on plunker/codepen/jsfiddle or another site of a sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this ended up being more complicated as to why it wouldn't work (had to have a friend help me rewrtie the method) partly due to how I had the db set up that it was pulling associations from (lodash had to get involved).

but regrding the checkboxes in case anyone is looking for checkbox and state help in the future thi sis what worked:

```
         <div className="doubleCol">
            {this.state.symptoms.map(item => (
               <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
                   <input
                      name="slector"
                      type="checkbox"
                      className="sympSelect"
                     onClick={() => this.setState(prevState => ({ selectedSymptom: [...prevState.selectedSymptom, item] }))}

                            />
                              {item.name}
                   </ListItem>
                ))}
            </div>
```

as for the rest of the method issues I will update the gist in the first post if anyone is actually interested.

Answer (score 1):

onChange on checkBoxes has been problematic for many users. See this:
[React Checkbox not sending onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615779/react-checkbox-not-sending-onchange)

On this thread you would find people suggesting onClick or some other ways to implement this functionality. I could have added this as a comment but i dont have 50 reputation :(

Comment: I deliberately do not have a `checked` property because i had read about it casuing issues, but did not know about `onChange` so i went ahead and made ii `onClick` instead

Comment: no, unfortunately while that may have helped it didnt fix it so that it filters

Comment: Can you share your code on plunker/codepen/jsfiddle or another site of a sort?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to catch the onChange event of CheckBox using  `ReactBootstrap`.

***my index.html***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="author" content="Binyamin (Benny) Regev">
    <meta name="course" content="Web Dev App - July 2019">
    <meta name="meeting" content="31 React Summary Exercise">
    <title>Todos List App</title>

    <!-- React -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Axios (used for AJAX calls) -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<!-- React-Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<!-- Local JS/JSX -->
<script type="text/babel" src="App.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

my ***app.js*** - only relevant code fragments 
(app.js doesn't contain any imports)

```
class FormTodos extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      newTask: '',
      show: false,
      nextIndex: 1,
    }
    this.onCheckBoxChanged = this.onCheckBoxChanged.bind(this);
  }

  onCheckBoxChanged(event) {
    // Just to show an indication that I got in the function
    console.log("onCheckBoxClick(event) --> ElementId = " + event.currentTarget.id);
  }

  render() {
    // Your code goes here :-)

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactBootstrap.Form.Check type='checkbox' id='check-api-checkbox' className="mb-2" size='lg'>


          <ReactBootstrap.Col lg='1'>
            <ReactBootstrap.InputGroup.Checkbox id={`checkbox${todo.id}`}
              style={styleCheckBox} checked={!todo.isActive}
              todoId={todo.id} label={todo.text} aria-label={todo.text}
              onChange={(item) => this.onCheckBoxChanged(item)}
              isActive={todo.isActive} />
          </ReactBootstrap.Col>

        </ReactBootstrap.Form.Check>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice the `onChange={(item) => this.onCheckBoxChanged(item)}`?
[image: And this is the output on the console]

I hope this helps.