# onChange function on checkbox isn't working | ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, function, onchange

I'm learning ReactJS and today I can't resolve a difficulty, so I need your help.

I want to make a "Remember Me" for users that want to stay connected after reopening the website.

This is my code :

My function :

```
handleChangeCheckBox = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.checked)

  this.setState({
    isChecked: event.target.checked
  })
}
```

When I call the function in the input checkbox field with an onChange :

```
<p>
  <Input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rememberCheckbox"
    className="rememberCheckbox"
    id={this.state.isChecked}
    onChange={this.handleChangeCheckBox}
  />
  Remember Me
</p>
```

Nothing appears in my console when I click on the checkbox, so it seems like the calling function isn't working.

Comment: What `Input` component is that?

Comment: It's a reactstrap Input

Comment: Look like you are using UI kit, or you should change ```<Input/>``` to ```<input/>```

Comment: Please refer link for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615779/react-checkbox-not-sending-onchange

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/rememberme-input-3rz12

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem. my state changes when I click on it but doesn't show in the checkbox

Answer (score 3):

please try this. replace `value` with `checked`

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    name="rememberCheckbox"
    checked={this.state.isChecked}
    onChange={this.handleCheckBox}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Code tested at given url 
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-checkbox-check?file=index.js)

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isChecked: false };
  }

  handleCheckBox = event => {
    console.log(event.target.checked);

    this.setState({
      isChecked: event.target.checked
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

       <p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="rememberCheckbox"
            value={this.state.isChecked}
            onChange={this.handleCheckBox}
          />
          Remember Me
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Your solution isn't working, but thanks for your help !

Comment: Your code is working at the url you gave but on mine, when I correct everything it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow!

Based on the code you shared, your function should be getting executed. I suspect you have an error somewhere else in your class rather than in those two code snippets you shared.

You can check this simple sandbox I made with a very barebones implementation like the one you have: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-simple-check-box-7etp4

One thing you're missing is using the `checked` html attribute rather than `id`. That's what will tell the checbox whether it's checked or not. It replaces the `value` attribute you use for input fields.

You also seem to be using an `Input` component. Try changing it for a normal HTML `input` instead.

Answer (score 0):

it could be triggering twice.

if you are using `create-react-app` then your `App`component is wrapped in `StrictMode` like this:

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>,
```

go to **`index.js`** and remove `<React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode>`

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-390206425

Answer (score 0):

handleChangeCheckBox = () => { this.setState({ isChecked: ! this.state.isChecked }) }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).